# start/stop button radio stream service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, audio-streaming

I have the code of a radio stream app from this site [radio stream example](https://github.com/pratamawijaya/example/tree/master/Example_StreamingAudio), but when i want to stop the stream it restarts. The only way to stop it is exit the app and get back to the app via the "recent apps" button or notification screen.

Can someone help me with the code?

StreamService.java

```
package id.pratama.example.streamingaudio.service;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import id.pratama.example.streamingaudio.MainActivity;
import id.pratama.example.streamingaudio.R;

/**
 * Created by pratama on 4/22/14.
 */
public class StreamService extends Service implements
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    /**
     * for educational only
     */
    // public static final String URL_STREAM = "http://jkt.jogjastreamers.com:8000/jisstereo?s=02766";

    // radio UNISI
    public static final String URL_STREAM = "http://202.162.32.23:8000";

    // notification
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    private boolean isPausedInCall = false;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    //intent
    private Intent bufferIntent;

    public static final String BROADCAST_BUFFER = "id.pratama.example.streamingaudio.broadcastbuffer";

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("create", "service created");

        bufferIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_BUFFER);

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("play", "play streaming");

        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            pauseMedia();
                            isPausedInCall = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            if (isPausedInCall) {
                                isPausedInCall = false;
                                playMedia();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        initNotification();

        mediaPlayer.reset();

        /**
         * play media
         */
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try {
                Log.d("streamm", "" + URL_STREAM);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL_STREAM);

                // sent to UI radio is buffer
                sendBufferingBroadcast();

                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        stopMedia();
        stopSelf();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int extra) {
        switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error not valid playback", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error server died", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error unknown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // sent to UI, audio has buffered
        sendBufferCompleteBroadcast();

        playMedia();
    }


    private void pauseMedia() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    private void playMedia() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    private void stopMedia() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    /**
     * sent buffering
     */
    private void sendBufferingBroadcast() {
        bufferIntent.putExtra("buffering", "1");
        sendBroadcast(bufferIntent);
    }

    /**
     * sent buffering complete
     */
    private void sendBufferCompleteBroadcast() {
        bufferIntent.putExtra("buffering", "0");
        sendBroadcast(bufferIntent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("tag", "remove notification");
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }

        if (phoneStateListener != null) {
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }

        cancelNotification();
    }

    /**
     * show notificaiton
     */
    private void initNotification() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Stream Radio")
                .setContentText("895 JIZ fm");
        builder.setContentIntent(intent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    }

    /**
     * cancel notification
     */
    private void cancelNotification() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        builder.setOngoing(false);
    }


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package id.pratama.example.streamingaudio;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import id.pratama.example.streamingaudio.service.StreamService;
import id.pratama.example.streamingaudio.utils.Utils;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Intent serviceIntent;
    private Button btnPlay;
    private static boolean isStreaming = false;
    private ProgressDialog pdBuff = null;
    private boolean mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, StreamService.class);
        isStreaming = Utils.getDataBooleanFromSP(this, Utils.IS_STREAM);
        if (isStreaming)
            btnPlay.setText("Stop");
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == btnPlay) {
            Log.d("playStatus", "" + isStreaming);

            if (!isStreaming) {
                btnPlay.setText("Stop");
                startStreaming();
                Utils.setDataBooleanToSP(this, Utils.IS_STREAM, true);
            } else {
                if (isStreaming) {
                    btnPlay.setText("Start");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Stop Streaming..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    stopStreaming();
                    isStreaming = false;
                    Utils.setDataBooleanToSP(this, Utils.IS_STREAM, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastBufferReceiver);
            mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(broadcastBufferReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    StreamService.BROADCAST_BUFFER));
            mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    private void startStreaming() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start Streaming..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        stopStreaming();
        try {
            startService(serviceIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    private void stopStreaming() {
        try {
            stopService(serviceIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastBufferReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent bufferIntent) {
            showProgressDialog(bufferIntent);
        }
    };

    private void showProgressDialog(Intent bufferIntent) {
        String bufferValue = bufferIntent.getStringExtra("buffering");
        int bufferIntValue = Integer.parseInt(bufferValue);
        switch (bufferIntValue) {
            case 0:
                if (pdBuff != null) {
                    pdBuff.dismiss();
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                pdBuff = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                        "Streaming...", true);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

Comment: @DeshanR that didn't work but i got the answer myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**finally figured it out myself!**

edit the **MainActivity.java** and use this code

```
package id.pratama.example.streamingaudio;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import id.pratama.example.streamingaudio.service.StreamService;
import id.pratama.example.streamingaudio.utils.Utils;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Intent serviceIntent;
    private Button btnPlay;
    private static boolean isStreaming;
    private ProgressDialog pdBuff = null;
    private boolean mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, StreamService.class);
        isStreaming = Utils.getDataBooleanFromSP(this, Utils.IS_STREAM);
        if (isStreaming)
            btnPlay.setText("Stop");
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == btnPlay) {
            Log.d("playStatus", "" + isStreaming);

            if (!isStreaming) {
                btnPlay.setText("Stop");
                startStreaming();
                isStreaming = true;
                Utils.setDataBooleanToSP(this, Utils.IS_STREAM, true);
            } else {
                if (isStreaming) {
                    btnPlay.setText("Start");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Stop Streaming..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    stopStreaming();
                    isStreaming = false;
                    Utils.setDataBooleanToSP(this, Utils.IS_STREAM, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastBufferReceiver);
            mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(broadcastBufferReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    StreamService.BROADCAST_BUFFER));
            mBufferBroadcastIsRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    private void startStreaming() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start Streaming..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        stopStreaming();
        try {
            startService(serviceIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    private void stopStreaming() {
        try {
            stopService(serviceIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastBufferReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent bufferIntent) {
            showProgressDialog(bufferIntent);
        }
    };

    private void showProgressDialog(Intent bufferIntent) {
        String bufferValue = bufferIntent.getStringExtra("buffering");
        int bufferIntValue = Integer.parseInt(bufferValue);
        switch (bufferIntValue) {
            case 0:
                if (pdBuff != null) {
                    pdBuff.dismiss();
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                pdBuff = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                        "Streaming...", true);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```